# Change the style of notification bar

Tags: css, angular

I have implemented a notification bar, using [ngx-notification-bar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-notification-bar)

[image]

In the `app.component.ts` file, the following part of the code is there

```
this.notificationBarService.create({ message: 'Free Shipping on Order above RM 150', type: NotificationType.Info, allowClose: true, autoHide: false, hideOnHover: false });
```

And in the `app.component.html`

```
<notification-bar></notification-bar>
```

I need to change the style of the text, background color, and the position of the `X` in the notification bar. Can anyone please tell me how to change the style ?

Answer (score 1):

Use **isHtml** property to change the style of text, Pass the message with html tags

Comment: I tried by setting isHTML property to true, but how to change the position of `X` icon? Can you please help me with this ? I need to place the `X` icon in the extreme right of the screen, so I need to use `float:right` style, for that purpose. So how should I add this style in message ?

Comment: I am only able to make the font bold/italic, how can I change the other properties as well like font size, font etc ?

Comment: You can add a class in your html message for example <p class="test-color" style = "font-color:yellow">Adjustments made in <b> <i> Other Income <i></b> as <b> <i>$1,235,407<i></b></p>.
and define that styles in your css .

Comment: thanks ;-) And, can you please tell me how can I change the position of the `X` icon and use the `float: right` property on it. So that it is placed in the extreme right of the screen.